# Bootstrap App.init() and FormComponents.init() don't let jquery work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

This is the built-in code in the template:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // initiate layout and plugins
    App.init();
    FormComponents.init();
});
```

If I include a jquery-popup like:

```
$(function () {
     ...
     ...
     $("#create-user").button().click(function () {
          $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
     });
});
```

it doesn't work. If I remove the App.init() and FormComponents.init(), it then works.
If I place my jquery script above App.init() and FormComponents.init(), it pops up for a second and disappears. How can I deal with it?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: can you add the script inside `jQuery(function ($) {});` - also whether the dom ready handler is getting called

Comment: can you add `console.log($("#create-user").length)` before the click handler is added

Comment: Pop up page is displayed in the main page. Button didn't work either. I have added console.log(..). How can I infer sth of that?

Comment: you can check the value of the `console.log()` using [browser console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)

Comment: $("#create-user").length = 1

Comment: is it from the logged value or did you manually run the command `$("#create-user").length` in your console

Comment: this is from logged value. From watch expression.

Comment: I was thinking the button was generated dynamically so when the script was executed the click handler is not added... since you are getting `1` in the console.log that is not the case.... else it looks fine to me

Answer (score 0):

please try like this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // initiate layout and plugins
         jQuery("#create-user").click(function () {
              jQuery("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
         });
        App.init();
        FormComponents.init();
    });
```

Comment: Now pop up opens for a second and then disappears.

Comment: can you please update your full code or create fiddle